# Split javaString into substring of characters and numeric value

Tags: java, string

My Requirement is like , split the given string into sub strings of charter and numeric values. 
And the input value will always begin charter only.

Input : `String strValue = "ABCD12345";`
Out put: 
A1 = ABCD 
A2 = 12345

Answer (score 2):

You need to use lookaround assertions.

```
String s = "ABCD12345";
String parts[] = s.split("(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=\\d)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

`(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=\\d)` regex would match the boundary which exists between alphabets and digits. Splitting according to the matched boundary will ive you the desired output.

Output:

```
[ABCD, 12345]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably some mistakes and probably not the most efficient here but here's a vauge shot. Feedback welcome of course.

```
var char;
var = num;
str = "somestring23498";

for(i=1:1=str.length - 1;i++){
   if ((typeof str[i] + 1) == "string"){
      char = char + str[i];
   } else if((typeof str[i] + 1) == "integer"){
      num = num + str[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively create a char buffer with space or a delimeter between char boundary.

String str = "ABCD1234cda209ad";

```
    char[] chars = new char[2*str.length()];

    int i=0;
    boolean isPrevcharANum = false;

    for(char c:str.toCharArray()){
        if(Character.isDigit(c)){
            if(!isPrevcharANum){
                chars[++i] = ' ';
            }
            isPrevcharANum = true;
        }else{
            if(isPrevcharANum){
                chars[++i] = ' ';
                isPrevcharANum = false;
            }
        }
        chars[++i] = c;
    }
    System.out.println("Output : "+new String(chars));
```

Output : ABCD 1234 cda 209 ad

Answer (score 0):

*again with regex but shorter*

```
String parts[] = s.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");  // [ABCD, 12345]
```

Internally, `split()` uses a `Pattern` to find the place where to split. The first part in braces is a *positive lookbehind*.
`\D` is the oposite to `\d` and means each character but a digit.
The second part in braces is a *positive lookahead* `\d` which means here must be a digit.
So a split is made when to the left of the position is any character but a digit and at the same time there is a digit in this position.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it